# How to not show a record in an array adapter based on IF criteria in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Hi I have an array adapter that is populated from an array like so:

```
 private class PlacesDetailAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceDetail> {

    private ArrayList<PlaceDetail> items;

    public PlacesDetailAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PlaceDetail> items) {


        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);


        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.placedetail_list_row, null);
            }
            PlaceDetail o = items.get(position);

            if (!o.getType.equals("place") {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeDetailTitle_Txt);
                    tt.setText(o.getName());

                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.placeDetailIcon_Img);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(o.getImage);

            }
            return v;
    }
}
```

The problem is that objects with type equal to place are still output as rows.

In addition I try to remove the objects from the array above the IF like so:

Iterator iter = m_orders.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    PlaceDetail vs = (PlaceDetail)iter.next();
                    if(vs.getType().equals("place")) {
                        m_orders.remove(vs);
                    }
                }

```
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When I do this, I get a concurrent editing exception.

How I simply limit rows of a certain type from being displayed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your second question, you're not allowed to modify a list directly while an iterator is traversing it, as doing so could theoretically cause the iterator to fail in a number of ways (skip elements, get stuck in an infinite loop).  There is, however, a remove() method on Iterator that will remove the last item returned from next(), which should do what you want here:

```
Iterator iter = m_orders.iterator(); 
while(iter.hasNext()){ 
    PlaceDetail vs = (PlaceDetail)iter.next(); 
    if(vs.getType().equals("place")) { 
         iter.remove();
    } 
}
m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Another way of approaching your problem might be to define a Cursor that traverses your list, only stopping at the items you want, and then using a CursorAdapter rather than ArrayAdapter.  It's a bit more work, but has the advantage that it doesn't require any up-front processing, so might be a bit more responsive.